# Как получить нужную часть xml в xmlpullparse?

Tags: android, xml, xmlparser

Есть шаблон XML, для разбора исп-ю XmlPullParser:

```
<XML>
  <client>
    <tag>text</tag>....<tag>text</tag>
  </client>
  <client>
    <tag>text</tag>....<tag>text</tag>
  </client>
  <client>
    <tag>text</tag>....<tag>text</tag>
  </client>
</XML>
```

Мне нужно, в цикле while как-то получить поочередно(string, array... в данный момент не важно):

```
new_clint="<client>
             <tag>text</tag>....<tag>text</tag>
           </client>"
```

Каким образом можно реализовать это, подскажите пжл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодится.
Решение исп. DOM parse:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(data)));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("client");  

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {  
   Node nNode = nList.item(i);     
   Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
   System.out.println("[" + i + "] -> " + nodeToString(nList.item(i))); 
}
```